# VBA Web Scraping: How do you save a pdf doc to your personal folder

Tags: vba, excel

Is there away to save a pdf Document opened in an IE Web Browser to your personal desktop folder using VBA? sorry, I don't have code, because I really don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: One option would be to make IE print the screen contents and direct it to a virtual PDF printer driver, but the result will not be the exact same PDF.  I'm not sure if you can access the PDF viewer inside IE and direct it to print, which is what you are asking for.

Comment: maybe try urlmon?

Answer (score 0):

You can try SendKeys. I am sure you will be able to resolve your problem. [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx) for more details about SendKeys

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use this code `Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long` to bring the IE to the foreground so that I can use the SendKeys, but its causing this error `Compile Error: only comments may appear after end sub, end function or end property` any ideas on how to resolve this?